# Pytorch3d error: from lib.colab_util import generate_video_from_obj, set_renderer, video

Tags: path, mp4, helper, opencv, pytorch3d, python

It's my first time programming.

I've got this error. How do I fix this?

from lib.colab_util import generate_video_from_obj, set_renderer, video

renderer = set_renderer()
generate_video_from_obj(obj_path, out_img_path, video_path, renderer)

## we cannot play a mp4 video generated by cv2

!ffmpeg -i $video_path -vcodec libx264 $video_display_path -y -loglevel quiet
video(video_display_path)

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 from lib.colab_util import generate_video_from_obj, set_renderer, video
2
3 renderer = set_renderer()
4 generate_video_from_obj(obj_path, out_img_path, video_path, renderer)
5

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytorch3d/renderer/blending.py in ()
7
8 # pyre-fixme[21]: Could not find name `_C` in `pytorch3d`.
----> 9 from pytorch3d import _C
10
11

ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pytorch3d/_C.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3c104impl23ExcludeDispatchKeyGuardC1ENS_11DispatchKeyE

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.